# C++17 MSVC Assigning function pointer to constexpr class member

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working with an array library and am trying to build some classes on top that can parametrize dispatching to functions which retrieve the type of scalar used within each array. The code looks something like this:

```cpp
class AnArray { ... };

class IntArray : public AnArray {
public:
  using ArrowScalarT = int64_t;
  using GetFuncPtrT = ArrowScalarT (*)(const struct ArrowArrayView *, int64_t);
  static constexpr GetFuncPtrT ArrowGetFunc = &ArrowArrayViewGetIntUnsafe;
  ...
};

class StringArray : public AnArray {
public:
  using ArrowScalarT = struct ArrowStringView;
  using GetFuncPtrT = ArrowScalarT (*)(const struct ArrowArrayView *, int64_t);
  static constexpr GetFuncPtrT ArrowGetFunc = &ArrowArrayViewGetStringUnsafe;
  ...
};
```

I am separately writing templated algorithms against those arrays that use these functions like so:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void SomeAlgorithm(const T& obj) {
  struct ArrowArrayView* array_view = ...;
  int64_t index = ...;
  const auto value = T::ArrowGetFunc(array_view, index);
  ...
}
```

The `ArrowArrayViewGetIntUnsafe` and `ArrowArrayViewGetStringUnsafe` functions are coming from a third party library. They are declared like:

```c
static inline struct ArrowStringView ArrowArrayViewGetStringUnsafe(
    const struct ArrowArrayView* array_view, int64_t i) { }

static inline int64_t ArrowArrayViewGetIntUnsafe(
    const struct ArrowArrayView* array_view,int64_t i) { }
```

GCC/Clang both seem happy with this pattern, but MSVC is not. yielding `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'ArrowStringView (__cdecl *)(const ArrowArrayView *,int64_t)' to 'const StringArray::GetFuncPtrT'` with the suggestion that `This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or parenthesized function-style cast`

I am confused as to what MSVC wants to have happen here. `reinterpret_cast` is not an option because we are assigning a function pointer to a `constexpr` member. Trying to use a C-style cast of `(GetFuncPtrT)&ArrowArrayViewGetStringUnsafe` in turn yields `a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered` and adding `const` to that cast makes no difference.

Is there any way to make this work with MSVC?

Comment: How are `rrowArrayViewGetIntUnsafe` and `ArrowArrayViewGetStringUnsafe` declared?

Comment: They are static inline functions from a third party library. Updated the OP to reflect that

Comment: The calling convention `__cdecl` makes all the difference. You can't convert a non-`__cdecl` function to a `__cdecl` function pointer.

Comment: Sounds reasonable but doing `#ifdef _MSC_VER` and within that branch changing the pointer declarations to `using GetFuncPtrT = ArrowScalarT(__cdecl *)(const struct ArrowArrayView *, int64_t)` makes no difference

Comment: `ArrowStringView` in `StringArray` is not the same `ArrowStringView` used in `ArrowArrayViewGetStringUnsafe`. The elaborate type specifier introduces a nested type `StringArray::ArrowStringView`. At least, it does in MSVC; I'm not sure this is the correct standard-conforming behavior when the declaration of `::ArrowStringView` is visible. Anyway, to resolve the issue, simply drop all your `struct` keywords. E.g. make it just `using ArrowScalarT = ArrowStringView;`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik wow that was it! Happy to accept that if you'd like to convert your comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your liberal use of elaborate type specifiers is what triggers the problem. You see, when you write

```
class StringArray : public AnArray {
public:
  using ArrowScalarT = struct ArrowStringView;
  using GetFuncPtrT =
    ArrowScalarT (*)(const struct ArrowArrayView *, int64_t);
};
```

this is equivalent to

```
class StringArray : public AnArray {
public:
  struct ArrowStringView;
  using ArrowScalarT = StringArray::ArrowStringView;
  using GetFuncPtrT =
    StringArray::ArrowStringView (*)(const struct ArrowArrayView*, int64_t);
};
```

The elaborate type specifier implicitly declares the nested class within the scope of `StringArray`. At least, that's what happens with MSVC: I'm not sure whether this is a bug or standard-conforming behavior.

At this point, it should be obvious why this creates a problem. `GetFuncPtrT` is a pointer to function returning `StringArray::ArrowStringView`, whereas `ArrowArrayViewGetStringUnsafe` is a function returning `::ArrowStringView`, a different type. Hence type mismatch.

The solution is to drop `struct` keywords everywhere (except where it's used to actually define a struct, of course). Don't use elaborate type specifiers; and especially don't use them within the body of a class definition. Make it simply

```
using ArrowScalarT = ArrowStringView;
```

Comment: Thanks! The only place MSVC really required dropping the struct keyword was in the using declaration